# Populate sqlite3 database from csv: Syntax error around '?'

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

Following a previous post concerning the population of a sqlite3 database from a csv file in python, I have used the code exactly as written but keep coming up with: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "Z:/KS4/Computer Science/OCR corsework/Task 1 Database/populate.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

This is the code:

```
import csv, sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("TutorGroup.db")

with open ('studentsEmail-master.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = next(r) 
    query = 'insert into dbo.students ({0})'
    query = query.format(','.join('?' * len(data)))
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()
```

Comment: What was the contents of `query`? Can you print that out?

Comment: you're missing the *`values`* keyword.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

You need the word `values` in the query:

```
query = 'insert into dbo.students values ({0})'
#                                 ^^^^^^
```